# Use specific consumer per element type with Java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm having a Java 8 stream of numbers:

```
Stream<Number> numbers = ...;
```

I'd like to iterate the stream and invoke a specific consumer based on the type of each element. I.e. for `Integer` elements I'd like to invoke a `Consumer<Integer>`, for `Long` a `Consumer<Long>` etc.

There is the `forEach()` method but this expects a `Consumer<? super Number>`, requiring that implementation (usually a Lambda expression) to instanceof-switch on the exact type itself.

In terms of an API, I'm essentially looking for something like this:

```
numbers.forEach( callbacks -> {
    callbacks.on( Integer.class, i -> { /* handle Integer */ } );
    callbacks.on( Long.class, l -> { /* handle Long */ } )
} );
```

Is there any existing API which would allow me to register a specific consumer per stream element sub-type in a way similar to this?

Comment: I don't know of any existing library that does exactly this, but based on the API sketch you've done, it looks fairly easy to implement.

Comment: As a work-around, you could write a single call-back (maybe with a factory built in) that distributes the work to the appropriate worker.

Comment: @biziclop, yes, it's not hard to implement (that's what I started with, but then I started to wonder whether I'm re-inventing the wheel here).

Comment: You could write such an API. Usually, you would use polymorphism and call the same method on all instances.

Comment: Btw what is the source of that stream? I'm just curious about what produces different type numbers. It might be easier to restructure the source

Comment: I chose `Number` as a commonly known example, but actually it's about a specific type hiearchy from my application. I considered the usual double-dispatch pattern where call execution is routed through the iterated elements, but the proposed API above grew on my because it doesn't require the iterated hierarchy to be enabled for double-dispatch and handlers for specific types can be registered as Lambdas, also only for a subset of all the existing sub-types.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you go with your original design - a class hierarchy intended to be used this way *should* be built to work with the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you don't want to just run the stream twice?  It will be more readable.

But if you want, you can define a type-checking consumer like this:

```
public static<T> Consumer<Object> acceptType(Class<T> clazz, Consumer<? super T> cons) {
    return t -> {
        if (clazz.isInstance(t)) {
            cons.accept(clazz.cast(t));
        }
    };
}
```

You can then combine multiple consumers using `andThen`:

```
Consumer<Object> combined = acceptType(Integer.class, i -> ...)
                   .andThen(acceptType(Long.class, lng -> ...))
```

If you want to hide `andThen`, you can define

```
static<T> Consumer<T> doAll(Consumer<T>... consumers) {
    return Arrays.stream(consumers)
            .reduce(Consumer::andThen)
            .orElse(t -> {});
}
```

Then it becomes

```
nums.forEach(doAll(
            acceptType(Integer.class, i -> ...),
            acceptType(Long.class, lng -> ..),
            ...
));
```

Comment: What are the readability problems of returning t -> Optional.of(t).filter(clazz::isInstance).map(clazz::cast).ifPresent(consumer) in acceptType?

Comment: Well, it will blow up on `null` values, which may or may not be what OP wants.  Other than that, a matter of personal preference.

Comment: When the decision to execute a block of code or another one depends on the class of an object, I immediately suspect of a bad design. This construct with `Consumer.andThen()` seems very elegant, though. But if you look closely, you'll quickly realize that the `Consumer.andThen()` chain (and also the `doAll(consumers)` approach) is no more than a big `switch` statement that is processed for each element of the stream. As @LouisWasserman commented below the question, this should be implemented with the visitor pattern.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. The `andThen()` chain is what I was looking for. I disagree with other commenters stating that solving this problem without double-dispatch/visitor is a design smell. Visitors add complexity and not each hierarchy one needs to traverse may have been designed with that in mind. Also e.g. take a look at the hierarchy of `javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror`, where a method `getKind()` is provided to "switch" on the type and allow for simpler code than with visitors. Essentially, it's a shortcoming of Java, that matter can be solved much nicer in other languages such as Ceylon.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know about such built-ins, so here is an option: Gather all the `Consumer`s in a `Map` keyed by the type it consumes, and look up the right consumer. I would recommend this solution if you work with a lot of types, and those types can change dynamically. The most efficient solution (by cpu consumption) would probably be to use a `switch` on `item.getType()`.

```
public class Casts {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stream<Number> stream = Arrays.stream(new Number[] { 3, 4L });

        Map<Class<?>, Consumer<? super Number>> consumers = new HashMap<>();
        putCastConsumer(consumers, Long.class,
                i -> System.out.println("Mapped long " + i));
        putCastConsumer(consumers, Integer.class,
                i -> System.out.println("Mapped int " + i));

        consumeByType(stream, consumers);
    }

    public static <U, T extends U> void putCastConsumer(
            final Map<Class<?>, Consumer<? super U>> map,
            final Class<T> clazz,
            final Consumer<T> consumer) {
        map.put(clazz, value -> consumer.accept(clazz.cast(value)));
    }

    public static <T> void consumeByType(
            final Stream<T> stream,
            final Map<Class<?>, Consumer<? super T>> consumers) {
        stream.forEach(item -> consumers.get(item.getClass()).accept(item));
    }
}
```